# CSS Issue (Height of Table Column)

Tags: css

```
<div class="panel_content" ng-controller ="TableCtrl">
  <table summary="A table listing various other formats for this product">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col" class="site amount"><span>B</span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><spanC</span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>D</span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span></span></th>
          <th scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span></span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="active">
        <th scope="col"><a href="#">Hardcover</a></th>
        <td scope="col" class="site amount"><span>R&nbsp;300.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;334.99</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;269.99</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>E</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>D</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#">Paperback</a></th>
        <td scope="col" class="site amount"><span>R&nbsp;150.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;169.99</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;119.99</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>E</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>D</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#">Audio, CD, Audiobook, Unabridged</a></th>
        <td scope="col" class="site amount"><span>R&nbsp;80.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;89.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;60.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>E</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>D</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#">Unknown Binding</a></th>
        <td scope="col" class="site amount"><span>R&nbsp;50.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;50.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>R&nbsp;50.00</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>E</span></td>
        <td scope="col" class="market_place amount"><span>D</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I recently got a Visual Design from UX Designer My task is to convert this VD into html file.I'm facing difficulty in setting CSS of B C and D column respectively.
How to increase height of column B C D with respect to column A.

Here is snapshot of Visual Design[image]

Comment: Post some code. so we can help

Comment: Reappear your issue in jsbin.com or codepen.io or jsfiddle.com. It may be get favor from others easily.